# How to get group of selected value in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I want to use grouped options. I want to get group of selected value.
For example when I selected green, how can I know it is a color?

sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-x3l2c4?file=/example.tsx

Color --> red, yellow, green

Flavor --> Vanilla, Chocolate

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

import Select, { components, MenuProps } from 'react-select';
import {
  ColourOption,
  colourOptions,
  FlavourOption,
  GroupedOption,
  groupedOptions,
} from './docs/data';

function onChangeHandler(val){
  console.log("val:" ,val)
}


export default () => (
  <Select<ColourOption | FlavourOption, false, GroupedOption>
    defaultValue={colourOptions[1]}
    options={groupedOptions}
    onChange={onChangeHandler}
  />
);
```

Comment: You can add `type` into each option, ie: type:'color', type:'flavour'. Or not recomended way: you can check if color is not undefined (flavour does not have color field)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to know about all selected options and at the same time you also want to know which option belongs to which group.

You can not do this by default, however you can customize your group options and
add another key which can indicate group reference/name so this way when `onChange` callback will be triggered you will get that option and you can see your group reference/name.

Check out this example and live-demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-helkl8?file=/example.tsx).

```
import React from "react";

import Select from "react-select";
import {
  ColourOption,
  FlavourOption,
  GroupedOption,
  groupedOptions
} from "./docs/data";

function onChangeHandler(val, meta) {
  console.log(val, "val");
  const selectedOptions = val;
  let goupedSelected = new Map();
  selectedOptions.forEach((option) => {
    const { groupName: key } = option;
    const found = goupedSelected.get(key);
    if (found) {
      found.options = [...found.options, option];
    } else {
      goupedSelected.set(key, {
        groupName: key,
        options: [option]
      });
    }
  });
  console.log([...goupedSelected.values()]);
}

export default () => (
  <Select<ColourOption | FlavourOption, true, GroupedOption>
    options={groupedOptions}
    onChange={onChangeHandler}
    isMulti={true}
  />
);
```